# New bike wheels dont sit in dropouts perfectly, are washers safe to use?

Tags: road-bike, wheels

I recently upgraded my road bike from Vision Team 30's to Mavic Ksyrium Elite UST wheels,  However once I got the wheels and put them on, the rear wheel seems to rub on the brake hardware when riding.  When I put the bike on a hanger and spin the wheel, it seems fine, but every time I ride, I can feel resistance, as if I'm riding with the brake slightly engaged.  I messed around with the quick release and found out that even with it tightened as much as humanly possible, The rear axles seem to almost be a little too short, and I think this causes them to sit slightly loose in the rear dropouts, despite the skewer being tightened all the way.  I tried using the QR skewer that came with the wheels, but it is worse than the ones that came with the Vision wheels, so I've been using them, but still have a bit of play with the rear wheel.  From the looks of it, I could throw a washer in between the axle and the frame to have it sit snug, but I'm wondering if this is safe or not? By my estimates, the gap with the new wheels is maybe 1-2mm, just about the size of a washer.

I was under the impression (not knowing much about road bikes) that all wheel axles had the same width, is this not true?

Update: photo showing washer and problem area:
[image]

It seems the washer works great.  No more wobble in the wheel, no more rubbing.

Comment: Not quite clear what is going on here. Are you saying that with eth wheel installed and QR done up the wheel can move a little between the dropouts?

Comment: Are you sure the axle is moving in the frame rather than the wheel moving on the axle? You should be able to tighten the QR enough to squeeze the frame to the width of the axle nuts, even if they are spaced narrower than your frame is designed for.

Comment: WRT to frame widths, modern road bikes are generally 130 mm between rear dropouts but some hybrids, cyclocross, and touring frames use 132 or 135. New wheels are either 130 or 135, so 132 spacing is intended to be compatible with both. Older wheels and frames are often 126, so if your new wheels were set up for an older bike they might be 126.

Comment: Could you post a photo of each of the drop-outs with the wheels tightened in place?

Comment: Have you compared the width of both rims? It is quite possible that the Mavics are slightly wider and that you have to open the brakes' barrel adjusters by a turn or two if the pads are too close to the rims.

Comment: Are the new wheels nrand new or used?. Check the hub is assembled properly - especially the spacers (8) https://tech.mavic.com/tech-mavic/technical_manual/data/mavic_tech.php?display=product&family=1010&subfamily=1050&macronu=25674

Comment: Can you add photos of the problem, and clarify what you mean when you say width? I don't really follow the problem

Comment: TBH sounds like your brake caliper needs repositioning is all.

Comment: @Criggie there definately was a problem.  with the QR skewer clamped down as much as humanly possible, I could stiill grab the wheel and move it a good 1/4" or so around in the dropouts.   I ended up adding a washer I had which fit perfectly and it so far has caused zero issues (picture updated)

Comment: @EvanR.fair enough - you should add that as an answer.

Comment: Did you add a washer on both sides so that the wheel sits in the middle of the frame?

Comment: In the photo, it looks as if the QR skewer is not closed all the way, bc the seatstay is in the way. Open the skewer, rotate it away from the seatstay and close it all the way.

Comment: @Michael only to the one side, I only had one at the time, the other side fit ok, and the wheel looks centered...I'll probably  end up taking it to my local bike shop when I get a chance to have them investigate, the QR is shut all the way, the Mavic skewer doesn't close very far but it's both torqued as tight as possible and closed all the away.  I can rotate it slightly back but where it's at is the tightest i can get it.

Comment: I'd like to agree with what the previous user said, it's good practice not to close the quick release on the frame as this can sometimes make it seem closed all the way, but it's actually being stopped by the frame. Face it straight backwards or straight down instead. This will also just make it easier to open as you don't have to try and get your fingers between the lever and the frame; I can't count how many people have come into my shop insisting that it's closed all the way, but it's actually not.

Answer (score 3):

could it simply be that the new rim is a few millimeters wider and the brakes are making contact because of that? If the wheel is seated into the dropout all the way, the quick release will have enough force to fully clamp the frame to the hub securely. Check by unclamping the qr, putting some body weight on the saddle with a shoulder and reclamp the qr. Beyond that, mattnz's suggestion above is possible. The whole hub assembly/bearings might be too tight or too loose, which is an easy fix.